# Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists and that it is less than 1.

Tags: calculus

If $f: [1, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable where $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 +[f(x)]^2}$ and $f(1) = 0$, prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists and that it is less than 1.

I believe I have shown that the $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x) \le 1$, but I can't get the strict inequality $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x) < 1$. Here is what I did:

To show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists, it suffices to show that $f$ is strictly increasing and bounded above. Observe that $x^2 +[f(x)]^2 \ge 1$ whenever $x \ge 1$. Thus $f'(x) > 0$ if $x \ge 1$, so that $f$ is strictly increasing. Also if $x \ge 1$, we have
$$\frac{1}{x^2 +[f(x)]^2} \le \frac{1}{x^2}$$
so that
$$\int_1^x\frac{1}{t^2 +[f(t)]^2}dt \le \int_1^x\frac{1}{t^2}dt$$
The above reduces to
$$f(x) \le 1 - \frac{1}{x}, \quad x \ge 1$$
That is $f(x)$ is bounded above by 1, so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)\le 1$.

Comment: $f'$ is strictly positive, so make a statement about that inequality on the open interval $(1,x)$ instead of the closed interval.

Comment: It is not uncommon for Mathematicians to say less than for $\le$ and strictly less than for $ <$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Strict inequalities become loose inequalities in the liimit, so you comment does not help.

Comment: You should look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1151614/72031 and note that $f(x) <L=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) $ and hence we can integrate $f'(t)>\frac{1}{t^2+L^2} $ over $[1,x]$ and continue as in my answer in the linked thread. The limit $L$ is root of $L^2=\arctan L$ with $L\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) > 1/2$.  Then by the intermediate value theorem, there is some $c>1$ such that $f(c)=1/2$.

By your estimate, $$\tfrac12 = f(c) \leq 1-\tfrac1c$$ or $c\geq 2$.  Now we can use your method again
$$\int_c^xf'(t)\,dt=\int_c^x\frac1{t^2+(f(t))^2}\,dt\leq \int_c^x\frac1{t^2+\tfrac14}\,dt=2\arctan(2x)-2\arctan(2c)\leq 2\arctan(2x)-2\arctan(4)$$

It follows that $$f(x) \leq \tfrac12+2\arctan(2x)-2\arctan(4)$$
so that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\leq \frac12+\pi-2\arctan(4)\approx 0.989957326253728$$

Comment: Nice approach (+1).